# Shortcut to autocomplete method input parameters VS10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In **VisualStudio 2010**, i'd like to create a keyboard shortcut when i have a method like this (with n Parameters)

```
public void MyMethod(type Parameter1, type Parameter2,..., type ParamenterN){    
      _object.MyMethod(type Parameter1, type Parameter2,..., type ParamenterN);
}
```

and MyMethod is like this

```
public void MyMethod(type Parameter1, type Parameter2,..., type ParamenterN){
     // Some code
}
```

where method *name/type parameters* are same for the method called, there is a **shortcut** to **autocomplete** input when i'm writing _object.MyMethod(

Comment: if you mean that you are using this code so often , then you can create a code snippet.

Comment: Now I see. and the answer is NO :). there is no such thing.